# .php files doesn't work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I think I broke mi VS Code trying to join php and html syntax when I have a php file with html and php code.

The problem is that VS Code doesn't recognize .php files. The Select Language Mode shows as a 'Plain Text' and when I try to configure file association for '.php' doesn't appear.

I try a solution found "php.validate.excecutablePath" and I did not have results.

[image: Screenshoot (php file unrecognized, message error, user setting solution without results]

Finally I tried installing again VS Code after uninstall and delete all but doesn't work.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: what machine are you running vs code on? and what version of vs code? reading through some similar issues [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/251) and some suggest adding php to your path variable (if on windows)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Windows and VS Code version 1.21.0.

Comment: The problem is that if I search in my settings I don't have default settings for php. I think I deleted trying to install and uninstall extensions.

Comment: The default settings for php in vs code are the following, open settings and check if they are there and if not add them back, :
  // Configures if the built-in PHP language suggestions are enabled. The support suggests PHP globals and variables.
  "php.suggest.basic": true,

  // Enable/disable built-in PHP validation.
  "php.validate.enable": true,

  // Points to the PHP executable.
  "php.validate.executablePath": null,

  // Whether the linter is run on save or on type.
  "php.validate.run": "onSave",

Comment: Hi kimcodes, thanks!
When I add this settings it shows a message like in the image "Unknow configuration setting".

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late lmao, but here's what I found; In order to make the setting re-appear, uninstall any extra php related extensions and restart vscode (you might also want to disable and re-enable php through searching "@builtin php" in extensions). That should bring the option back; then go and set up the path in the settings.json, and if you are a windows user add it to your environmental variables (specifically path).